# CSS margin gap on top, right, and left

Tags: css

Why are there gaps on top, right, and left of my horizontal navigation bar? I don't want these gaps. I just want the navigation bar to start from 0,0 of the viewport, so that there's no screen space wastage.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    #nav {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #nav li {
        width:25%;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #nav li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.5em 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #F2F2F2;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
    }

    #nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
        background-color: #071726;
    }

    #nav a:hover, #nav a:active, #nav a:focus {
        background-color: #326773;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wq6x2/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: @user2834739 here looking done. i have no looking gap you write *{margin:0;padding:0;} in your stylesheet

Comment: sorry, i didn't see the selector '*'

Answer (score 0):

By default the document/body has a margin. you can "disable" it by setting the following css rule.

```
body, html{margin:0;padding:0}
```

Comment: @user2834739 padding is not mandatory here, see my posted answer

Comment: no it isn't necessary. But everyone does it inclusive me :-). It is the margin from the body that gives the "gap".

Comment: However, there can be differences in browsers so it is recommended to do like stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is [reference](http://jsbin.com/IvIlIJO/1)

Make it as

```
body{
  margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: @user2834739 you are welcome, see posted JSBin. Please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you reset your css? Else use (in the top of your css file)

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a reset/normalize css:
[normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/),
[reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

you should also read [this](http://sixrevisions.com/css/should-you-reset-your-css/) for better understanding of things.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **margin** and/or **padding** to **`0`** in the main navigation element or the links.

```
nav li { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0; 
}
```